# Edit View Templates for Razor Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm writing web application using razor view engine. In Visual Studio I got the chance by RightClicking "Views"-Folder in project-explorer to create a view using a wizard. I can check "Create strong typed view", select a model-class and template (e.g. Empty, List, Create, Delete, ...). Nice thing.

I wonder how I can edit the templates (change language, css styles, ...).

The default create-Template looks like this:

```
 @model UsedModel

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "DefaultTemplate";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 <h2>DefaultTemplate</h2>

 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <fieldset>
         <legend>UsedModel</legend>

         <p>
             <input type="submit" value="Create" />
         </p>
     </fieldset>
 }

 <div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>
```

So how can I customize this template?

Thanks in advance
Tobi

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/simonc/archive/2010/08/17/94124.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a SO question that has the answer I believe you are looking for:
[How do I edit default Razor Creat/Edit scaffolding in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894077/how-do-i-edit-default-razor-creat-edit-scaffolding-in-visual-studio-2010)

You can either copy the T4 files to your project and edit them (recommended) or modify them in place for all projects to use (I recommend against this).